# Using wildcard domains in sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I need to add functionality a bounce handler for multiple virtual domains that are constantly dynamic. I have over 1,000 domains that change (additions & deletions) on an hourly basis. Essentially, when an unsubscribe request, bounce, or a XDATA complaint comes in, it will go to one of several email addresses including bounce@whateverthedomainis.net

The functionality I need to add is to set up sendmail to relay all bounce@* and abuse*@* to an IP that acts as a smarthost. All other emails must be processed locally as there are automated mailboxes on the machine that process formatted emails.

I originally had it set up to where my bounce server was an open relay to the smarthost IP and I was assured that they would handle security, however they didn't and we quickly became a relay for spammers.

Comment: "constantly dynamic" and the need to match "abuse*@*" would point me towards a milter solution, e.g. mimedefang that would then read from a database or such when deciding what to do with a mail.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual domains" from sendmail perspective?  How do you (want to handle) other address in the virtual domains?

Answer (score 0):

If you have virtual domains that are constantly dynamic, then you must already have a process for dynamically adding and removing them. Why not simply include some virtusertable entries in your existing automated process?

Someone signs up abc.com, instead of just a virtual domain, also create bounce@abc.com and whatever@abc.com. You can state the routing for that address right in the same line in the virtusertable.

Virtusertable details:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/sendmail.html